# Dynamic sql is not working in restore database version 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Friends...

Os: win2k3

DB: sql server 2008

I am planning to restore the latest backup set from production to test db. i have to get the max position from the restore headeronly command to a variable and pass it to restore command.

i have written this query..but iam still facing some problem in executing this query.

```
declare @position1 as int

declare @tempsql1 nvarchar(max) 

set @tempsql1='RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = ''D:\DailyDBbackup\ciet.BAK''';

execute(@tempsql1); ======== upto this statement working fine...

SELECT @position1 = MAX(position) FROM @tempsql1 WHERE BackupType = 1 AND BackupName = 'ciet-Full Database Backup';
```

Here `@tempsql1` is not getting the value from the above variable. I am getting the error as

> Must declare the table variable "@tempsql1"

:

```
RESTORE DATABASE ciet FROM DISK = 'D:\DailyDBbackup\ciet.BAK'
WITH  FILE = @position1;
```

can anybody correct this error?

thanks & regards

i have tried like below query...but again its restoring the old backupset not the max one.

```
DECLARE @position1 int;
DECLARE @BackupHeader TABLE (
        BackupName nvarchar(128)
        ,BackupDescription nvarchar(255)
        ,BackupType smallint
        ,ExpirationDate datetime
        ,Compressed tinyint
        ,Position smallint
        ,DeviceType tinyint
        ,UserName nvarchar(128)
        ,ServerName nvarchar(128)
        ,DatabaseName nvarchar(128)
        ,DatabaseVersion int
        ,DatabaseCreationDate datetime
        ,BackupSize numeric(20,0)
        ,FirstLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,LastLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,CheckpointLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,DatabaseBackupLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,BackupStartDate datetime
        ,BackupFinishDate datetime
        ,SortOrder smallint
        ,CodePage smallint
        ,UnicodeLocaleId int
        ,UnicodeComparisonStyle int
        ,CompatibilityLevel tinyint
        ,SoftwareVendorId int
        ,SoftwareVersionMajor int
        ,SoftwareVersionMinor int
        ,SoftwareVersionBuild int
        ,MachineName nvarchar(128)
        ,Flags int
        ,BindingID uniqueidentifier
        ,RecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier
         --following columns introduced in SQL 2008
        ,Collation nvarchar(128)
        ,FamilyGUID uniqueidentifier
        ,HasBulkLoggedData bit
        ,IsSnapshot bit
        ,IsReadOnly bit
        ,IsSingleUser bit
        ,HasBackupChecksums bit
        ,IsDamaged bit
        ,BeginsLogChain bit
        ,HasIncompleteMetaData bit
        ,IsForceOffline bit
        ,IsCopyOnly bit
        ,FirstRecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier
        ,ForkPointLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,RecoveryModel nvarchar(60)
        ,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0)
        ,DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier
        ,BackupTypeDescription nvarchar(60)
        ,BackupSetGUID uniqueidentifier NULL 
        ,CompressedBackupSize bigint
        --following column introduced in SQL 2012
        --,Containment tinyint 
    ) 

INSERT INTO @BackupHeader
    EXEC ('RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK=''D:\DailyDBbackup\121213\ciet.BAK''');

--print @BackupHeader; ==== it shows error so i commented

SELECT @position1 = MAX(position) 
FROM @BackupHeader
WHERE
    BackupType = 1 
    AND BackupName = 'ciet-Full Database Backup';

print @position1; ==== here it shows the first position that is 1...max position is 18

IF @position1 IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Backup not found', 16, 0);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RESTORE DATABASE ciet FROM DISK = 'D:\DailyDBbackup\121213\ciet.BAK'
        WITH  FILE = @position1;
END;
```

Comment: Your `@tempsql1` variable is just a simple nvarchar value. You cannot do a `SELECT ... FROM @tempsql1` as it is not possible to SELECT from a simple nvarchar value.

Comment: what are you expecting to be in @tempsql?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough - you can't use @tempsql1 such way, is **not** a table variable.

There is no easy way, to put a **select SQL** to variable, then to **from** clause.

If you consist on dynamic SQL generation - read this short guide

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html